# JQ fadeTo working on consolelog but not on browser

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
$('.parent div').on('click',function(ev) {
  $(ev.currentTarget).fadeTo(500,0).delay(501).hide(0);
});



$('#showAll').on('click', function(ev) {
  $('.parent div').slideDown().fadeTo("slow",0.99);

})
})

   </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent" data-name="parent">
  PARENT
  <div class="child" data-name="child 1">CHILD 1</div>
  <div class="child" data-name="child 2">CHILD 2</div>
  <div class="child" data-name="child 3">CHILD 3</div>
</div>
<button id="showAll">Show All</button>



</body>
</html>
```

For some reason the fadeTo at the end is not working and I get an empty div thats open up.

I run on chrome console.log -

```
$('#showAll').on('click', function(ev) {
  $('.parent div').slideDown().fadeTo("slow",0.99);
```

And its works just fine. Any Idea why its not working as it should on my browser?

Cheers to all.

Comment: Works for me? http://jsfiddle.net/rvn2sceo/

Comment: Yes the code is fine I ran a file with the same name but not the same folder. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem with missing semicolons, this should fix it too and i think its more clear:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.parent').on('click',function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(500,0).delay(501).hide(0);
            });

            $('#showAll').on('click', function() {
                $('.parent').slideDown().fadeTo("slow",0.99);
            });
        });
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent" data-name="parent">
  PARENT
  <div class="child" data-name="child 1">CHILD 1</div>
  <div class="child" data-name="child 2">CHILD 2</div>
  <div class="child" data-name="child 3">CHILD 3</div>
</div>
<button id="showAll">Show All</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/snq47dxd/